# How to do left join/look-up in mongoDB to return the count for the users id in each organization?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have 20 objects of organization and and 100+ users. I want to retrieve result for number of total employee each organization have ?

I am trying aggregation look-up. But it's returning me empty array.

```
        let data = await organizationModel.aggregate([
            {
                $lookup: {
                    from: "employees",
                    localField: "_id",
                    foreignField: "organizationId",
                    as: "output",
                },
            },
        ]);
```

Organization Object :

```
{
_id: ObjectId(213eawsdzamxxca23fccce1)
orgName: alphaprintings
orgPhone:4543 343 122
orgLocation: Atlanta, USA
orgEmail: contact@alphaprintings.com
}
```

Employee Object :

```
{
_id: ObjectId(431aacff90uhcce1)
empName: Steven Decker
empPhone:4543 343 122
empLocation: Atlanta, USA
empEmail: steven@alphaprintings.com,
organizationId: 213eawsdzamxxca23fccce1
}
```

Comment: Where is the `organizationId` defined?

Comment: @prasad_ Sorry I have just added foreign key in employee object. Please review my question and code again. Thanks.